# It says [object Object][object Object] when I add two things

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

When I run the code (see gist) chance makes a 40 string long number set that then gets used to make another number set. This number see normally looks like this.
0.8492767284624279
0.23668391536921263
Then I try to add the two to one another and I get [object Object][object Object] in the console.

I dont really know what to try. Google has not helped me

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
var Chance = require('chance');
var chance = new Chance();
//getting everything I need
var 1 = chance.hash({length: 40})
var 2 = chance.hash({length: 40})
//makes two hashes
console.log(1)
console.log(2)
//logs the two hashes
var out1 = new Chance(1);
var out2 = new Chance(2);
//uses the two hashes above to make new numbers

console.log(out1.random());
console.log(out2.random());
//logs the new numbers
var roundOutcome = out1 + out2; 
// Above is where the issue happenes.
console.log(roundOutcome) 
//this is where it puts the [object Object][object Object] in console
```

It should add the two numbers. I dont really know what to do here. 
It always says [object Object][object Object] no matter what.

Comment: Does it even evaluate to that position? `var 1` is a SyntaxError?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var roundOutcome = out1.random() + out2.random();
```

you didn't call the methods.

Fun fact: If you add two random numbers, the result is less random than the numbers itself.